# Use the Fedora Yum command after installation, how to configure

Tags: linux, configuration, yum, installation, eclipse

When i use command "yum install exlipse*"after installtion, display eclipse-cdt,but in eclipse cannot edit C/C++ project, not clear when Yum after general to eclipse do configuration

Answer (score 0):

Yum doesn't perform any sort of configuration; it is up to the packages themselves to supplement other packages' configuration or to supply a configuration of their own.